# How to run a task ONLY on modified file with Gulp watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have the current gulp task which I use in a gulpfile. Path are from a config.json and everything works perfectly:

```js
//Some more code and vars...

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch([config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.png", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.jpg", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.gif", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.jpeg"], ['imagemin-cfg']);
})

//Some more code ...

gulp.task('imagemin-cfg', function () {
    return gulp.src([config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.png", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.jpg", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.gif", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.jpeg"], {read: false})
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngcrush()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildType))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

But I still have an issue, the number of images in my project is huge and this task takes ages. I'm looking for a way to run my task ONLY on modified files. If I had an image or modify it, `imagemin()` will only run on this image, and not on all.

Once again everything is working perfectly fine, but the run time is really long.

Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

"gulp-changed" is not a best solution for doing this, because it watch only modified filed in "buildType" folder.

Try [gulp-cached](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-cached) instead.

Comment: This made a world of difference and was really easy to implement. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Worth noting that gulp-cached's cache is empty on first run. So, if you rely on it, your first run of the watch task will affect all files given to it. Not a big deal for some scenarios, but it caught me off-guard.

Answer (score 37):

Another option is to used the gulp.watch on("change") option.

```
gulp
  .watch([config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.png", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.jpg", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.gif", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.jpeg"])
  .on("change", function(path) {
      gulp
        .src(path)
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngcrush()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildType))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
  });
```

Comment: If you use this method, then you will have to handle the relative destination path of the file yourself, because gulp doesn't do itself.. at least it works at end :)

Comment: This is perfect. I just needed the pattern to edit only specific files which get changed.

Comment: It's so weird that the gulp website [says](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/watching-files/#using-the-watcher-instance), "You likely won't use this feature," when it seems really useful. I wish they wouldn't do that. Makes it seem like I shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 21):

No need for plugins, this can be achieved with just gulp.watch.

With gulp.watch, you can target **the changed** file like this.

```
gulp.watch(["src/**/*"], function (obj) {
 return gulp.src(obj.path, {"base": "src/"})
 .pipe(gulp.dest("dest"));
});
```

Edit: **for Gulp v4.0.2 - Now fixed:**

```
const { watch, src, dest } = require('gulp');

var watcher = watch(["src/**/*"]);
watcher.on('change', function(fileName){
    return src(fileName, {base: 'src/'})
        .pipe(dest('dest'));
});
```

Comment: When I do this I get invalid glob argument error: undefined.

Comment: What is your task name, try changing it?

Comment: "obj" in `'change', function(obj)` seems a little misleading. callback is invoked with the path (string) of changed file.

Comment: True, changed the parameter name to `fileName`.

Answer (score 9):

Incremental builds are supported natively in Gulp without any plugins since version 4.0. Here is the example taken from the [project README](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp#incremental-builds):

```js
const paths = {
  ...
  images: {
    src: 'src/images/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}',
    dest: 'build/img/'
  }
}

function images() {
  return gulp.src(paths.images.src, {since: gulp.lastRun(images)})
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.dest));
}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch(paths.images.src, images);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest [gulp-newy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newy) in which you can manipulate the path and  filename in your own function. Then, just use the function as the callback to the `newy()`. This gives you complete control of the files you would like to compare.

This will allow 1:1 or many to 1 compares.

```
newy(function(projectDir, srcFile, absSrcFile) {
  // do whatever you want to here. 
  // construct your absolute path, change filename suffix, etc. 
  // then return /foo/bar/filename.suffix as the file to compare against
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, gulp-changed does exactly that:

```
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

gulp.task('imagemin-cfg', function () {
return gulp.src([config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.png", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.jpg", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.gif", config.path.devfolder+"/**/*.jpeg"], {read: false})
    .pipe(changed(buildType))
    .pipe(imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
        use: [pngcrush()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildType))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a real-world example I use all the time to do this without the need for any additional packages. I use this to minify, rename and compile any .js file in the `js` directory. Compiled files are saved to a `dist` directory with `.min` appended before the extension.

```
// Compile JS
var compileJS = function( file ) {
    var currentDirectory = process.cwd() + '/';
    var modifiedFile = file.path.replace( currentDirectory, '' );

    gulp.src( modifiedFile )
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( rename( {
            suffix: ".min"
        } ) )
        .pipe( livereload() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'dist' ) );
};

// Watch for changes
gulp.watch( 'js/*.js', [ 'js' ] ).on( "change", compileJS );
```

The above answers seemed partially incomplete and a little unclear to me, hopefully this is helpful for anyone else looking for a basic example.

Comment: This is the most straight-forward answer, and it doesn't rely on processing every file and comparing with a cached version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the task or callback, you'll have an event parameter, which has a type property, which will tell you if the file was added, deleted or changed. Best bet is to make use of that in a conditional on your task.

```
gulp.watch('path to watch', function(event){
  if(event.type === 'changed') { 
    gulp.start('your:task');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the main task so that it accepts a parameter for the `.src()` input pattern. Define a wrapper function to pass a default src value for the task so that you can still call it directly like `gulp images`:

```js
const imageFilePattern = '/src/path/to/input';

function images() {
  getImagesTask(imageFilePattern);
}

function imagesTask(src) {
  return gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
}
```

Now you can easily define the watch task to only process changed files:

```js
function watch() {
  return gulp.watch(imageFilePattern).on("change", imagesTask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution for a similar issue with on change event using `changedFilePath` variable. (gulp v4.0.2)

I have `.js` for each `.cshtml` page in `.net` core. and I want to minify them all in a single folder with the same name on change.

```
"use strict";
var gulp = require("gulp"),
  jsmin = require("gulp-terser"),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  changedFilePath = '';


/* Gulp to minify JS files */
gulp.task("minify-js", function () {
  return gulp.src(changedFilePath)
    .pipe(jsmin())
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
      path.basename = path.basename.replace('.cshtml', '.min').toLowerCase();
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/bundle/dist/js/pages"));
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.watch("Views/**/*.cshtml.js").on('change', function (filepath) {
    changedFilePath = filepath;
    gulp.series('minify-js')();
    return
  });
});
```