# Gulp task to watch and transform changed file

Tags: gulp

There is the following gulp tasks:

```
// Processing templates task
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/**/*.slim')
      .pipe(slim({pretty: true}))
      .pipe(minifyHTML())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});

// Watching files for changes task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.slim', ['templates']); 
});
```

As you can see `templates` task finds and transforms all `.slim` files in `.html` file. It works good. Also there is `watch` task which watches changes and executes `templates` task after it. But I want that after `watch` task finds some changes in template A gulp will transform only template A, not all templates. I don't understand how I can get changed file and transform it. Please, help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [See this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890806/how-to-run-a-task-only-on-modified-file-with-gulp-watch).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try [Incremental build](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/docs/readme.md#incremental-build).

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.slim')
        .pipe(watch('app/**/*.slim'))
        .pipe(slim({pretty: true}))
        .pipe(minifyHTML())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
});
```