# Only run a gulp task if two files are different

Tags: gulp, webpack

I have a scenario where I only run a task (minify js) if two files are different. If they're the same, then I don't need to run.

Best way would be to first compare sizes, if they are different then the files are too. If they are the same, then compare contents and then decide if to run the task or not.

Can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a task ONLY on modified file with Gulp watch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890806/how-to-run-a-task-only-on-modified-file-with-gulp-watch)

Comment: @SvenSchoenung I am actually looking for a straight up diff. I will ALWAYS create a new file (using webpack). If the resulting file is the same as the old one, I don't minify it and just use the old minified version. If they are different, I minify the new file and replace the old minified with the new one.

Comment: This totally sounds like a task for [gulp-cached](https://github.com/contra/gulp-cached), as suggested in the answer to the linked question. Or maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: @SáT I looked into it, but won't work if the server restarts since it's in-memory.

Comment: Then use `gulp-cache` or `gulp-changed`.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung That worked. I didn't know there was an option to gulp watch files! Still not quite there since I need to "watch" and can't be a standalone process, but it's good enough for now. Thanks for the help